# why my link url to bad url on my site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

link urls is bad in server but correct in my local!

i use :

```
Url.Action("myaction", "mycontroller", new { id = a.Id, title = a.Title,Name="test", area = "" })
```

and :

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ViewRout",
            url: "{lang}/{Name}/{id}/{title}",
            defaults: new { controller = "mycontroller", action = "myaction", lang = "en", id = UrlParameter.Optional, title = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { id = @"\d+",                
            namespaces: new[] { string.Format("{0}.Controllers", typeof(RouteConfig).Namespace) }
        );
```

url in local :

```
/en/test/6546/title1
```

but, url in server (not always, often, sometimes just bad!) :

```
/x1(a)xsyidfjazxdfdsxd/en/test/6546/title1
```

please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your application is configured to enable cookieless sessions. This strange values in the URL are used to identify the sessions in case it can't use cookies for that. Please check "Enter Cookieless Sessions" section at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx